# Rejecting $H_0$ means accepting $H_1$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose we are sampling from $f(x;\theta)=\phi_{\theta,25}(x)$ and we are considering $H_0:\theta = 2$ vs $H_1: \theta \ne 2$.

One of these is true and the other false.

Suppose we also have a test $Y$ based on which, after we take the sample $(x_1, ... ,x_n)$, we decide to reject $H_0$.

**Does this mean that we accept $H_1$?**

If we were considering $H_0: \theta=2$ vs $H_1: \theta > 2$ and after a test we decided to reject $H_0$.

This doesn't mean that we accept $H_1$. **Is this correct? If so, why is it?**

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "accept" here. Rejecting H0 doesn't necessarily mean you must actually believe H1 is true, but it might be  that you choose to act as if it were. Rejection of a hypothesis implies that it's inconsistent with the data in the sense that you'd be pretty unlikely to see something at least this extreme if the null were true (to the extent chosen when you set your significance level) -- but less unlikely if it were false. To disbelieve the alternative would mean you'd need to think that you did actually get such an unlikely event -- (or that you doubt your assumptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H_0$ and $H_1$ must be mutually exclusive indeed and cover the whole solution space. $H_1$ is usually not very strictly defined, it is just *not* $H_0$. As a result rejecting $H_0$ always entails accepting $H_1$, but this latter statement does not mean much because of the very general form of $H_1$. In your second example $H_0$ should be $\theta\leq 2$ to cover the whole parameter space. Then rejecting $H_0$ will again imply that $H_1$ must be the right one.